# How to compute the geometric center of a curved manifold defined by a set of point?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, optimization, numerical-methods

Suppose that I have a set of points E which belong to a manifold. Typically a surface mesh [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noIIb.png).
$$E=\{x_{0},x_1,...,x_n\}$$ where the $x_i$ are the points coordinates in 3D such that : $x_i = (x_{i}^x,x_{i}^y,x_{i}^z)$

I would like to compute the centroid $c$ such that it's coordinates are the mean of the coordinates of all the points belonging to this manifold. 
But I don't want the metric to be the Euclidian distance (because the centroid will not be necessarily on the manifold).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your manifold is $S^1$ and $E = \{(1,0), (-1,0)\}$, where should the centroid be?

Comment: "the centroid will not be necessarily on the manifold" - that sounds to me as if you simply want the $\mathbb{R}^3$ coordinate wise arithmetic mean of the points?

Comment: Maybe you can use the formula here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145964/centroid-of-manifold ?